# XMLHttpRequest HTTP and re-use of connections

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

Say one do multiple requests to `example.com/some/api` by XHR.

If one do:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https:/example.com/some/api?' + query);
xhr.send();
```

each time, does that make a new connection each time, handshake and all?

And if one reuse the `xhr` it re-uses the connection if kept alive?

Does it create a new connection each time, or re-use independent on the object, or anything in between?

From what I understand HTTP/2 does not have `keep-alive` but more in a way of *keep connection open as a default*. For HTTP/1.1 it depends on headers?

---

Main thought is that it is better to re-use the `xhr` if there is a new connection for each object. And on the contrary, if it is handled deeper in the system it's nothing much to twiddle with.

And as a second point is it enough to check for `readyState` if re-using? If it is `4`, is it OK to re-use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XHR persistent connection, how so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837660/xhr-persistent-connection-how-so)

Comment: @BadPiggie Thanks :) Perhaps. I do not quite get the process. I thought perhaps 1) One create a `XHR` object, 2) connect 3) resolve ... and then can use the *same* connection to to a second request. As in not a new connection, but re-use it - w/o a new handshake etc. The linked question is about *one* transfer that might be delayed (If I read it correctly), which is another topic.

Comment: I have found quite a few Q/A about reusing the XHR object as for performance etc. but I'm more interested in what happens *"behind the curtains"* and if re-use has a purpose in regard to bot client and server.